# Writing Join Query for a Many to Many relationship With Group By and Having clauses

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to return every order that has more than 2 products associated with the order. Order and Product have a many to many relationships as given below.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Order implements Serializable {

    public static final int PRECISION = 2;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String orderId;

    . . .  Other fields . . . .

    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_product",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", updatable = false, nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    )
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and Product

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String productId;

   . . . . Other fields
}
```

My SQL query would have been

```
SELECT o.order_id, p.product_id from Orders o join 
    OrderProduct op on o.order_id = op.order_id join Product p on   
    op.product_id = p.product_id group by o.order_id, p.product_id having    
    (p.product_id) > 2
```

My best attempt at writing this query

```
   @Query("SELECT o from Order o JOIN o.products where o.id = :id GROUP BY o HAVING (o.product) > 2")
  List<Order> findOrderWithMultipleProducts();
```

returns the following error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [id] [SELECT o from Order o JOIN o.products where o.id = :id]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:391) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:123) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

The controller merely calls this function directly. The desired JSON payload is something like this

```
{
         "orderId": "order_id",
         "products": [
             {
                 "productId": "product_id_1",
             },
             {
                  "productId": "product_id_2",
             },
             {
                  "productId": "product_id_3",
             }
         ]
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query has where clause as **:id** with : character. So hibernate is expecting a parameter

```
  @Query("SELECT o from Order o JOIN o.products where o.id = :id GROUP BY o HAVING (o.product) > 2")
  List<Order> findOrderWithMultipleProducts();
```

If somehow you can get the query creation and then set the parameter as :

```
SQLQuery query = SELECT o from Order o JOIN o.products where o.id = :id GROUP BY o HAVING (o.product) > 2
query.setString("id",ValueOfId);
```

Assumption id is type String

Other approach going ahead with the *@Query* annotations would be pass the parameter in your method and change the :id to reflect the parameter sequence.

```
@Query("SELECT o from Order o JOIN o.products where o.id = ?1 GROUP BY o HAVING (o.product) > 2")
List<Order> findOrderWithMultipleProducts(int id);
```

More Detail can be found here :
[Hibernate Query Annotations](https://ctpconsulting.github.io/query/1.0.0.Alpha5/annotations.html)

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but OP does not need the "where" clause if he is joining on a field.